# JSON Decode to MYSQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am having JSON POST like this.

```
{"item_sku":["016","APL","017"],"item_quantity":[2,4,1]}
```

I want to insert it into mysql database table and in column named 'item_sku' and 'item_quantity'. I guess this will insert three rows.

HTML Page:

```
  <form id="form1" class="p-md col-md-6" ng-submit="addOrder()">

  <ul class="list-group m-b-sm md-whiteframe-z0" ng-repeat="item in cart.items">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <a ui-sref="app.product({productSku: item.sku})" class="pull-right w-56"><img ng-src="http://192.168.0.228/app/{{ item.image || 'img/default_product.jpg' }}" alt="{{item.sku}}" class="img-responsive"></a>
      <div class="clear">
        <b>{{item.name}}</b><br>
        <span style="color:#666;font-size:12px;">{{item.description}}</span><br>
        <span style="color:#666;font-size:12px;">SKU# {{item.sku}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="sku[$index]" ng-init="sku[$index]=item.sku">
        <br><br>            
      </div>
      <div>
        <!-- use type=tel instead of  to prevent spinners -->
        <button
            class="form-control btn btn-grey" type="button" style="width:34px;background-color:#ddd;"
            ng-disabled="item.quantity <= 1"
            ng-click="cart.addItem(item.sku, item.name, item.price, -1)">-</button>
        <input
            class="form-control btn btn-grey" size="2" style="width:44px" type="tel"
            ng-model="item.quantity"
            ng-change="cart.saveItems()" />
        <button
            class="form-control btn btn-grey" type="button" style="width:34px;background-color:#ddd;"
            ng-disabled="item.quantity >= 100"
            ng-click="cart.addItem(item.sku, item.name, item.price, +1, $index)" >+</button>
            <input type="text" ng-model="quantity[$index]" ng-init="quantity[$index]=item.quantity">
      </div>    
    </li>

        <div class="p b-t b-t-2x">
            <a style="color:#666;" ng-click="cart.addItem(item.sku, item.name, item.price, -10000000)" >
            <i class="icon mdi-action-delete i-20" style="color:#666;"></i>Remove</a> 
            <span class="pull-right">{{item.price * item.quantity | currency:' &#8377; ':2}}</span>
        </div>  

  </ul>                 


   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info m-t" >Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('OrderCtrl', function($scope, $location, $http ) {
$scope.sku = [];
$scope.quantity = [];
    $scope.addOrder = function(){
        $http.post(serviceURL+'submit_order.php', {
                        'item_sku':$scope.sku,
                        'item_quantity':$scope.quantity
        })

        .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        $location.path('app/feedbackthankyou');
        });
    };  
});
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");

include "db.php";
// Using Static Data from POST -- Just for testing
$a='{"item_sku":["016","APL","017"],"item_quantity":[2,4,1]}';
$data = json_decode($a);
var_dump($data);

    foreach ($data as  $value)
    {
        echo $value->item_sku;
        echo $value->item_quantity;
    }
?>
```

I guess details are enough now. BTW I am using AngularJS to create CART. Please help.

Comment: what exactly do you need help with? you want code to insert data into a DB?

Comment: There are lots of guides on how to connect to and save data in a Database. I suggest you follow one of them with simple exercises, then try to apply it to your needs. If your code doesn't work, share your code and we'll help you.  Your question is too broad.

Comment: @BeetleJuice - I know how to insert it in mysql. But after json_decode my foreach is not giving me values in variables, otherwise I would have inserted it using mysql query. Please help.

Comment: show your complete code. Most of us are looking at several questions at a time. Help us to help you. We zoom back, pleas for help that are put together lazy-like, we just split.

Comment: @Sharry From the starting data you posted, what would you want your final variables to look like?

Comment: @Drew Complete code updated. I want to save cart items into database using item_sku and item_quantity on different rows.

Comment: @BeetleJuice I guess now you should have an idea of what I am trying to do. Please see updated code.

Comment: I wrote up a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shape of your data complicates the database insertion a bit. Data that should go in the same row is divided into two separate objects: `$data->item_sku` and `$data->item_quantity`.

It would be simpler if everything that should go in one row were together in one variable or one array element. I would change the shape of the data I submit. Instead of a `item_sku` and `item_quantity`, I would just submit `items`.

**Javascript**

```
var items=[];
for(var i=0; i<$scope.sku.length; i++){
   items.push({'sku':$scope.sku[i], 'qty':$scope.quantity[i]});
}
$http.post(serviceURL+'submit_order.php', {items:items})
```

Then on the **PHP side**

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['items'],true);
```

Now `$data` is an array of items with the shape:

```
[
    ['sku'=>'016','qty'=>2],
    ['sku'=>'APL','qty'=>4],
];
```

This can be more easily inserted in your database because the data is already organized in rows. You said you already know how to do DB inserts so I'll let you work out that part.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this shape and will let you know. Sorry in advance if I reply late. Getting fever now so moved to mobile app for replying. Thanks again.

Comment: @ BeetleJuice Its not pushing values to items array. {"items":[]}

Comment: Why not? What does it do instead? and what does the code look like?

Comment: This is my controller code now:

<code>
app.controller('OrderCtrl', function($scope, $location, $http ) {
 var items=[];
 var sku = $scope.sku;
 var qty = $scope.quantity;
    $scope.addOrder = function(){
  for(var i=0; i<sku; i++){
     items.push({'sku':sku[i], 'qty':qty[i]});
  }
  $http.post(serviceURL+'submit_order.php', {items:items})
    };  
});

Comment: Try changing `i<sku` to `i<sku.length` Also make sure that you actually call your `addOrder` function, not just define it. You'll notice that in my answer I don't have a function. I use the `For` loop directly.

Comment: Error: sku is undefined.
I am calling addOrder on ngSbmit.

Comment: Ok I get it. That's because you're not following my code pattern. You're trying to access `sku` from inside a function that is separate from where you define `sku`, and `qty`. I'm not doing that in my solution, because the loop needs to be in the same context as the variable declarations. Notice in my solution I declare the variables and immediately go into the `For` loop.

Comment: I defined sku and qty inside function, but still not working.

app.controller('OrderCtrl', function($scope, $location, $http ) {

    $scope.addOrder = function(){
  var items=[];
  var sku = $scope.sku;
  var qty = $scope.quantity;

  for(var i=0; i<sku.length; i++){
     items.push({'sku':sku[i], 'qty':qty[i]});
  }
  $http.post(serviceURL+'submit_order.php', {items:items})
    };  
});

Comment: "It's not working" is too vague. What happens? Any error details?

Comment: It seems that my HTML page is sending array to $scope.sku and $scope.quantity and as a variable sku and qty  is not getting any value in this. Thats why it pushing empty values to items array. What you say?

Comment: try removing `sku` and `qty` from the code, and using `$scope` directly. Look at my updated answer (Javascript portion). You may need to pass `$scope` as an argument to your `addOrder` function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I merged your and my code. And it worked. Please check if it is not vulnerable. I guess it won't.

app.controller('OrderCtrl', function($scope, $location, $http ) {
$scope.sku = [];
$scope.quantity = [];
var items=[];
    $scope.addOrder = function(){
  
  for(var i=0; i<$scope.sku.length; i++){
     items.push({'sku':$scope.sku[i], 'qty':$scope.quantity[i]});
  }  
  $http.post(serviceURL+'submit_order.php', {items:items})

  .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
  $location.path('app/feedbackthankyou');
  });
    };  
});

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Be sure to select my answer if it helped you solve your problem and upvote if you like it.